# copy and move files in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, file, copy, move

I am trying to copy or move files/directories in objective-c on the mac.
I woulf like to have something like the Finder, with a progress bar showing the operation progress for the set of file.

There are plenty of methods for that (NSFileManager, NSWorkspace, FSxxx)

Which one is the best one for my case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display a progress bar you should use the FS method. See [this article](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/05/03/cocoa-tutorial-file-copy-with-progress-indicator/) for more information.

Comment: It is not possible to have a progress indicator using NSWorkspace methods?

Comment: Well, the NSFileManager/NSWorkspace methods don't give you progress callbacks, so you can't show accurate progress with them.